# Change attachment name when sharing file to mail

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I am sharing a file using this code:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

The file name is: "a123456789cd.mp3". I can't change the actual file name so I need to change it only in the attachment into something meaningful like: "myRecording.mp3".
Is that possible ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no simple way around it given how android treats resources within an app. See this answer: [Email attachment send by app has different name than file that is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298758/email-attachment-send-by-app-has-different-name-than-file-that-is-sent)